# SQL Multi insert

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to multi insert in my table but getting error.

My query is:

```
insert into tbl_temp(e_id, t_id, status, type)
select id from tbl_basicinfo where emp_id = 91 and employee_id <> 7119, 289, 1, 2
```

it gives error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.

what is the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: 289, 1, 2 are hardcoded values that i want to insert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
insert into tbl_temp(e_id, t_id, status, type)
select id, 289, 1, 2 from tbl_basicinfo where emp_id = 91 and employee_id <> 7119
```